# Unable to find database in AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are using EC2 instance in AWS, my question is how we can find the database in AWS console? while we have already checked RDS, in RDS no DB instance is available, can someone guide what is the exact location to find the database in AWS ec2 instance?

Comment: What database?  If you didn't create one in RDS then there won't be one.  Do you have a local database?

Comment: I'm with @stdunbar on this. Either your question is not clear, or you are not understanding what RDS is, and how that is different than an EC2 instance with a database on it.

Answer (score 0):

Under Services in AWS console you can find and i have highlighted with red

[image]

[image]